# PHP readfile() echoes file content to the screen, but doesn't download

Tags: php

the code I am using:

```
function DownLoading($Peter)
{
//    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
//       ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off')
        $File = "";
    $Filename = "";
    If ($Peter == "Farm") {
        $File = "TestFile.txt";
        $FileName = $File;  //"TestFile.txt";
        $len = filesize($File); // Calculate File Size
        if (file_exists("TestFile.txt")) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TestFile.txt"');
            header('Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $len);
            ob_clean();
            $wasdownloaded = readfile("TestFile.txt");
            if ($wasdownloaded === false)
                echo "error";
            else {
                echo "no error";
                Flush();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that if I run this code on wamp server then it works fine (no echoeing, but downloading)

The following is echoed to the sdcreen: This is a test file!!! Nowno error
whereby "This is a test file!!! NOW" is the files's content

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");` ? Also, keep in mind that `header` works only if you haven't sent any data in your request.

Comment: Just tried that, same result.  What do you mean by "works only if you haven't sent any data in your request"?

Comment: Just as a side note, you assign `$File = "TestFile.txt";`, you then assign `$FileName = $File;` which does not seem necessary. But despite having these two variables containing your file name, you keep using the literal `TestFile.txt`. You may want to fix that.

Comment: That is basically because I have been trying all kind if things.  Could that be the cause?  If not, I'll fix it in the final version.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not the cause, but you still should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very stupid that was causing the same thing. Basically, as already said, you must ensure nothing has been sent already.

I had put a space before the `<?php` opening declaration - and that was the problem!

Comment: I went over the code with a "fine comb" , but no changes.  This drives me nuts!  I have been at it now for 3 weeks and no progress.

Comment: Thanks.  You got me on the right path!  I had outputted something before, but by moving the downloading routine to a separate file, it worked!